# Download and install .net framework 4.0 from installer without ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, inno-setup

I would like to use Inno Setup instead of ClickOnce to create my app installer, but I need to know how can I programmatically download and install .net framework 4.0 (if required) and the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 data provider (if required), the same way ClickOnce would do. This Inno Setup let me run exe's when installing so I would create a different app to download all the required stuff and run it at installation time. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CodeProject article describes how to do it for earlier versions of the .NET Framework:

> **[.NET Framework 1.1/2.0/3.5 Installer for InnoSetup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetfx_innosetup_instal.aspx)**

The script for .NET 4.0 should be very similar.